# Change name onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript that shows and hides a class

```
$(document.body).ready(function(){
var hidden=$('.hidden');
$('#slid').click(function(){
    if(hidden.hasClass('visible')){
       hidden.removeClass('visible');
    }
    else{
       hidden.addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

All I want is that the INFO name, once clicked, it changes its name in CLOSE.

https://jsfiddle.net/q6oe2c80/

Comment: how will you show the changed text if the element itself is hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) along with simple [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to achieve what you want,

```
$(document.body).ready(function() {
  var hidden = $('.hidden');
  $('#slid').click(function() {
    hidden.toggleClass("visible");
    $(this).text(hidden.hasClass("visible") ? "CLOSE" : "INFO")
  });
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q6oe2c80/1/)

Answer (score 0):

this is based on your fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/q6oe2c80/7/

```
 $(document.body).ready(function(){
 var hidden=$('.hidden');
 $('#slid').click(function(){
    if(hidden.hasClass('visible')){
       hidden.removeClass('visible');
       $(this).html("INFO");
     }
    else
    {
       hidden.addClass('visible');
       $(this).html("Close");
    }
 });});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the html inside #slid
https://jsfiddle.net/d2mbzLqw/

```
$(document.body).ready(function(){
var hidden=$('.hidden');
$('#slid').click(function(){
    if(hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.removeClass('visible');
        $(this).html("INFO");
    }
    else{
        hidden.addClass('visible');
        $(this).html("CLOSE");
    }
});});
```